# PHP OOP "Implementation must be compatible"

Tags: php, oop

I'm having weird problems with PHP OOP and type hinting. Here's an example:

```
abstract class AC {}

class C extends AC {}

interface I {
    function method(AC $abstract);
}

class InterfaceImplementation implements I {
    function method(C $concrete) {}
}
```

This code won't run, saying that `method` is not compatible with the interface declaration. I would think it is compatible since C extends AC - do I miss something? How am I expected to implement this sort of functionality?

Comment: I would not agree this is compatible, your `interface I` signifies a contract the `method` accepts _any_ `AC`, not just `C`... I would concur that `InterfaceImplementation` does NOT in fact implement `I`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine you have a class `B` which also extends `AC`. Then `I` requires that any of its implementations also accept `B` as argument to method. Your `InterfaceImplementation`, however, doesn't.

The bigger picture: You might want to reconsider your design if you need to specify a concrete type in the implementation. The idea is that to the outside world, all that needs to be known is encoded by `AC` and there should not be an `InterfaceImplementation` that ever needs to know which concrete subclass is being transferred. Maybe the specific stuff can be embedded in `C`'s code and generically called through a method exposed by `AC?`

Yet another update: You might be able to achieve what you want using generics, but I don't think they exist in PHP. I still think if you share the details of the design problem that might make another interesting question :)

Comment: It would accept `B`'s.... Unless you mean `B` extends `AC`, in which case you are correct.

Comment: sorry yea meant to say "extebs AC" not "extends C" -- fixed

Answer (score 1):

Just define it as :

```
class InterfaceImplementation implements I {
    function method(AC $concrete) {}
}
```

And call it with an instance of C, ie. `->method(new C());`.

The PHP reference manual on [Object Interfaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php) clearly states :

> The class implementing the interface must use the exact same method signatures as are defined in the interface. Not doing so will result in a fatal error.

Comment: yea but I guess he wants to restrict the InterfaceImplementation to only accept C arguments