# Interface implementation: declaration must be compatible

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, interface

I have the interface:

```
interface AbstractMapper
{
    public function objectToArray(ActiveRecordBase $object);
}
```

And classes:

```
class ActiveRecordBase
{
   ...
}

class Product extends ActiveRecordBase
{
   ...
}
```

========

But I can't do this:

```
interface ExactMapper implements AbstractMapper
{
    public function objectToArray(Product $object);
}
```

or this:

```
interface ExactMapper extends AbstractMapper
{
    public function objectToArray(Product $object);
}
```

I've got the error "**declaration must be compatible**"

Is there a way to do this in PHP?

Comment: I know this was posted a few years ago now but here's my two cents-

This error message isn't to do with interface inheritence.  This error is because PHP doesn't support true function/method overloading, like in other languages (e.g. Java, C++) that you're probably used to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP OOP "Implementation must be compatible"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862846/php-oop-implementation-must-be-compatible)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, an interface must be implemented *exactly*. If you restrict the implementation to a more specific subclass, it's not the same interface/signature. PHP doesn't have generics or similar mechanisms.

You can always manually check in code, of course:

```
if (!($object instanceof Product)) {
    throw new InvalidArgumentException;
}
```

Comment: but I try create another interface, based on that. Not implement, but inherit with restriction.

Comment: It doesn't really matter whether you extend or implement. You can't change an interface declaration, period. You can't say Foo implements Bar when Bar's implementation is much more restricted than what Foo specified.

Answer (score 3):

After 7.4, when support for covariance and contravariance was added, you could not do what you intend, but you'd be able to do exactly the opposite.

Contravariance means that a parameter type can be less specific in a child method, than that of its parent or interface.

E.g. given these two classes:

```
class Foo {}
class FooChild extends Foo {}
```

And and interface like this

```
interface A {
    public function a(FooChild $f): Foo;
}
```

You could have an implementation that would be:

```
class AI implements A {
    public function a(Foo $f): Foo
    {
        return $f;
    }
}
```

While the implementation does not follow the interface **exactly**, it's compatible, since any consumer of the `A` interface can still use the `AI` class safely, since anything that's legal on the interface is also valid on the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of implementing this would be:

```
class Executor
{
    public function objectToArray(AbstractMapper $var)
    {
        $this->convert($var);
    }

    private function convert(Product $var)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```