# When to redeclare class property in inheritance for stricter more explicit type defining

Tags: php, oop

Straight to the point.

```
abstract class AbstractRepository {

    private $mapper;

    public function __construct(AbstractMapper $mapper) {
        $this->mapper = $mapper;
    }

    public function save(AbstractEntity $entity) {
        return $this->mapper->save($entity);
    }

    public function delete(AbstractEntity $entity) {
        return $this->mapper->delete($entity);
    }

}

class UserRepository extends AbstractRepository {

    private $userMapper;

    public function __construct(UserMapper $userMapper) {
        parent::__construct($userMapper);
        $this->userMapper = $userMapper;
    }

    public function fetchByUsername($username) {
        return $this->userMapper->fetch( array('username' => $username) );

}
```

---

### VS

```
abstract class AbstractRepository {

    // Different visibility
    protected $mapper;

    public function __construct(AbstractMapper $mapper) {
        $this->mapper = $mapper;
    }

    public function save(AbstractEntity $entity) {
        return $this->mapper->save($entity);
    }

    public function delete(AbstractEntity $entity) {
        return $this->mapper->delete($entity);
    }

}

class UserRepository extends AbstractRepository {

    // $userMapper property gone

    public function __construct(UserMapper $userMapper) {
        parent::__construct($userMapper);
    }

    public function fetchByUsername($username) {
        return $this->mapper->fetch( array('username' => $username) );

}
```

I like the first way because it is more explicit and concrete that the `UserRepository` holds an instance of `UserMapper`.

The second way is better because there is less code but take the line

```
return $this->mapper->fetch( array('username' => $username) );
```

It is not as clear as

```
return $this->userMapper->fetch( array('username' => $username) );
```

When I am in the user repository I know that `$this->mapper` is an instance of a `UserMapper` but I prefer to address it like `$this->userMapper`.

Are there any rules on what is best to do in a scenario like this?

Thanks.

Comment: That doesn't work either way. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19131270/476

Comment: What do you mean doesn't work? As in it is wrong? Both ways run perfectly. I want to know which is the correct way.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19429089/override-method-parameter-with-child-interface-as-a-new-parameter for an explanation.

Comment: @deceze I've read that before. That is not my problem. My code works 100% both ways but I just want to know which is the better way to do it.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve. You could write setter/getter ala getUserMapper() to for every inheriting class to clarify what mapper you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first approach doesn't make sense... You are duplicating code.

What you have to understand is that `UserRepository` still has an `$mapper` property. It just is not directly accessible, because it is `private`. You'll need accessor methods to do it:

```
abstract class AbstractRepository {

    // Different visibility
    private $mapper;

    public function __construct(AbstractMapper $mapper) {
        $this->mapper = $mapper;
    }

    protected function getMapper() {
        return $this->mapper;
    }

    public function save(AbstractEntity $entity) {
        return $this->mapper->save($entity);
    }

    public function delete(AbstractEntity $entity) {
        return $this->mapper->delete($entity);
    }

}

class UserRepository extends AbstractRepository {

    // $userMapper property gone

    public function __construct(UserMapper $userMapper) {
        parent::__construct($userMapper);
    }

    public function fetchByUsername($username) {
        return $this->getMapper()->fetch( array('username' => $username) );

}
```

This way you can assure that any of the `*Repository` subclasses will do anything weird with `$mapper`, but you can still "read" it with `getMapper`.

Your second approach is also correct, but less restrictive.