# Override method to take argument from a derived subclass

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

I ended up a couple of times with a solution where i have two hierarchies of classes. Where classes from the first (Greeters) hiearchy uses classes from the second (Users).

Heres a ex:

```
class User {}
class Admin extends User {
    function getSecretMessage() {
        return "secret";
    }
}

class Greeter {
    public function hello(User $a) {
        echo "hello!";
    }
}

class AdminGreeter extends Greeter {
    public function hello(Admin $a) {
        parent::hello($a);
        echo "in addition heres a secret of mine: " . $a->getSecretMessage();
    }
}
```

Here i have User's and Greeter's, In PHP i receive the error (strict)

**"Declaration of AdminGreeter::hello must be compatible with Greeter::hello"**

I would like the `AdminGreeter::hello` to simply "extend" the `Greeter::hello` with data from a more specialized class (Admin).

What alternatives do i have to build something similar i PHP??

I guess the main problem is that PHP does not support "method overloading" and thereby if i were to send in a `User` instance to the `AdminGreeter` it would break. But if i had "method overloading", the `Greeter::hello` would simply be called if passed in a User instance.

It might be overall bad design, since i end up with this issue, maybe someone can point me to a better design for this problem.

*As i side note i seem to have the same issue when developing Objective-C*

Comment: `Admin` isn't a class, it's an [interface](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php)

Comment: thanks your right i should properly have used the wording "types" instead of "classes". I edited the questions to remove any confusion :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Interface inheritance - declaration must be compatible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19131157/php-interface-inheritance-declaration-must-be-compatible)

Comment: if you want to reuse code usually inheritance is not the way to go. it seems you want to achieve sth similar to visitor pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern take a look at decorator also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern

Comment: litechip, you are right the decorator pattern is much better suited for my problem. I felt that keeping a polymorphic interface was important, so i could call ::hello on each of the greeters and inject a instance of type User. I can see why you suggested the Visitor pattern, but for my problem (which is greatly simplified here) the decorator is a good solution thanks! - could you provide an answer please :) otherwise i will create an answer with the solution i created.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you might consider using [Traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) instead for these "specialized classes"

```
class User {
    protected $name;
    public function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
    public function __toString() {
        return $this->name;
    }
}

trait Admin {
    function getSecretMessage() {
        return "secret";
    }
}

class Greeter {
    public function hello(User $a) {
        echo "Hello ", $a, "!", PHP_EOL;
    }
}

class AdminGreeter extends Greeter {
    use Admin;
    public function hello(User $a) {
        parent::hello($a);
        echo "in addition heres a secret of mine: " . $this->getSecretMessage();
    }
}

$x = new User('Natalie');
$y = new AdminGreeter;
$y->hello($x);
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep with your original code as much as possible:

```
interface iUser {
    public function getSecretMessage();
}

class Admin implements iUser {
    function getSecretMessage() {
        return 'secrete';
    }
}

class Greeter implements iUser{
    public function hello( iUser $a ) {
        echo 'hello';
    }

    public function getSecretMessage(){}
}

class AdminGreeter extends Greeter {
    public function hello( iUser $a ) {
        parent::hello($a);
        echo ' in addition heres a secrete of mine: ' . $a->getSecretMessage();
    }
}

AdminGreeter::hello( new Admin );
```

Outputs `hello in addition heres a secrete of mine: secrete`