# Declaration not compatible with interface (PHP)

Tags: php, laravel, design-patterns

Let's say I have one parent class with two child classes like this

```
abstract class Vehicle {
    public function setManufacturer(string $manufacturer) { ... }
}

class Bicycle extends Vehicle {
    public function addSaddle() { ... }
}

class Car extends Vehicle {
    public function setSpeedLimit(float $limit) { ... }
}
```

Now I want to use these objects with an interface like this

```
interface VehicleInterface {
    public function create(Vehicle $vehicle);
}

class BicycleService implements VehicleInterface {
    public function create(Bicycle $bicycle) {
        $bicycle->setManufacturer('Some company'); // Common for all Vehicle objects
        $bicycle->addSaddle(); // Common only for Bicycle objects
    }
}
```

It seems that this is not possible since `BicycleService create(...)` is not compatible with the interface. Is there any way around this other than removing type hints?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862846/php-oop-implementation-must-be-compatible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this:

```
class NotBicycle implements Vehicle { ... }

interface VehicleInterface {
    public function create(Vehicle $vehicle);
}

class BicycleService implements VehicleInterface {
    public function create(Bicycle $bicycle) {
        $bicycle->setManufacturer('Some company'); // Common for all Vehicle objects
        $bicycle->addSaddle(); // Common only for Bicycle objects
    }
}

function createVehicle(VehicleInterface $service, Vehicle $vehicle) {
    $service->create($vehicle);
}
$service = new BicycleService();
$vehicle = new NotBicycle();
createVehicle($service, $vehicle);
```

Even if you were somehow able to only accept a `Bicycle` in the `BicycleService`, `createVehicle($service, $vehicle)` will still work because `VehicleInterface` has a method `create(Vehicle $vehicle)`. Therefore in order to get this to work the way you want it, you need to basically break what an interface is.

Your only real option is to add a runtime type check. Like e.g.

```
class BicycleService implements VehicleInterface {
    public function create(Vehicle $bicycle) {
        if (!$bicycle instance of Bicycle) { 
           throw new TypeError('Expected Bicycle but got '.get_class($bicycle)); 
        }
        $bicycle->setManufacturer('Some company'); // Common for all Vehicle objects
        $bicycle->addSaddle(); // Common only for Bicycle objects
    }
}
```

What you are trying to do is called a *covariant method parameter type* and is not allowed in most object-oriented programming languages because it breaks the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

Read more on [parameter covariance and contravariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science))

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the type `Bicycle` with `Vehicle`. You might have to check `if ($bicycle instanceof Bicycle)`

The abstraction level is too abstract.

For the kind of thing you are doing: Check out the Builder Pattern https://designpatternsphp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Creational/Builder/README.html

Answer (score 0):

when you implemts to your class you have to follow the contract.
So ever class the implemts the `Vehicle`  class must have `setManufacturer` method as you decleard.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your `Vehicle` class into it and then use `instanceof` to check the interface. In the below case, I changed the naming convention.

```
interface Vehicle {
    public function setSpeedLimit(Float $limit) : Car;
    public function setManufacturer(String $manufacturer) : MethodOfTransport;
}

interface NonVehicle {
    public function addSaddle() : Bicycle;
    public function setManufacturer(String $manufacturer) : MethodOfTransport;
}

abstract class MethodOfTransport
{
    public function setManufacturer(String $manufacturer) : MethodOfTransport { return $this; }
}

class Bicycle extends MethodOfTransport implements NonVehicle
{
    public function addSaddle() : Bicycle { return $this; }
}

class Car extends MethodOfTransport implements Vehicle
{
    public function setSpeedLimit(Float $limit) : Car { return $this; }
}

$b = new Bicycle();
$c = new Car();
```

As stated, I cleared up some confusion with naming conventions since a `Bicycle` is not a `Vehicle` but a `MethodOfTransport`.

```
interface VehicleServiceInterface
{
    # Change the return DataType to MethodOfTransport if Vehicle implements multiple classes
    public function create(MethodOfTransport $t) : Car;
}

class VehicleService implements VehicleServiceInterface
{
    public function create(MethodOfTransport $t) : Car
    {
        if (!$t instanceof Vehicle)
            throw new Exception( 'Cannot create a Vehicle on a NonVehicle instance.' );
            
        $t->setManufacturer( 'Foo' )->setSpeedLimit( 140 );
        return $t;
    }
}

$c = (new VehicleService())->create( $c ); // Works
$b = (new VehicleService())->create( $b ); // Throws Exception
```

Both `Car` and `Bicycle` are a `MethodOfTransport` however, one is a `Vehicle` and the other is a `NonVehicle`. Both can be passed into the method, but we can ensure that it is the correct type by using `instanceof`.

You can, however, set the return type to be of the `create` method to be of `Car` due to the fact we're filtering only the `Vehicle` instance in this case. If you have multiple `Vehicle` implemented classes, then change this to return `MethodOfTransport`

[See it working on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/ccumv).